# Java Could not find or load main class when trying to run fxml

Tags: java, linux, fxml

When I try to run a jar file that is compiled on netbeans in windows on a linux rasbian machine everything goes well , when I try to run a fxml jar file the following problem is returned 

"Could not find or load main class when trying to run 'classname' "
Everything is run as root in the same folder but only the fxml jar doesn't run!

EDIT 1
I used standard netbeans settings to build it

EDIT 2
 Content of problematic jar (All lines end with CR LF in notepad++)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: raspTest
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Permissions: sandbox
Codebase: *
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Class-Path: 
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Implementation-Vendor: AXANO
Main-Class: rasptest.RaspTest
```

Content of working jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_66-b17 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: rasp.Rasp
```

EDIT 3
 
installed netbeans in linux , when I run a fxml aplication in linux it runs OK but when I try to run it as a jar with java -jar name.jar I get the same error "Could not find or load main class..."

Comment: Did you build your project?

Comment: project is build and then moved on a linux pc

Comment: What's your command to run it?

Comment: Does the jar contain a file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`? What is the content of it? You can open the jar file with a tool like 7zip.

Comment: @mm759jes it contains the manifest

Comment: @mm759 i used the build icon of netbeans with standard values

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how NetBeans builds a jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the main class in the project. You can do so by:

1. right clicking the project and choose properties.
2. Choose run from the menu on the right.
3. Look at Main Class, and click browse on the left
4. navigate to your main class and press select main class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you got a correct manifest into the jar ?

In some case, windows and linux do not use the same line return format.
Windows use : `\r\n` and Linux use : `\n`

Hope that'll help

Comment: how do i check this?

Comment: Open with e. g. Notepad++ and enable to show invisible characters.

Comment: all files end with CR LF but the first one works nevertheless the other one doenst so i dont think this will be the problem